# FTP Azure 530 User cannot log in

Tags: ftp, azure

ftp to Azure webapp not working today... no clue what is happening. was working weeks ago in my last deploy.

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... Status: Initializing TLS... Status: Verifying certificate... Status: TLS connection established. Command: USER anonymous Response: 331 Password required Command: PASS ********************* Response: 530 User cannot log in. Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server

I'm using .publishingSetting file downloaded today

Somebody can give a help please?

Comment: Also experiencing similar issues. Seems to have started since the outage which hit Azure "SOUTH CENTRAL US" earlier in the week. Have dropped a support ticket which them.

Comment: For me was solved yesterday via MSDN

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4682069a-ca33-4691-81d2-1c2affec8191/ftp-azure-530-user-cannot-log-in?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview